# 256-bit encryption with small random alphanumeric password

Tags: encryption

We are considering using email to transmit PDFs containing personal health-related information ("PHI"). There is nothing of commercial value, no social security numbers or credit card numbers, or anything like that in these documents. Only recommendations for treatment of medical conditions.

The PDFs would be password-encrypted using Adobe Acrobat Pro's 256-bit password encryption.

Using very long passwords is not logistically desirable because the recipient of the emails with PDF attachment is the patient, not a technical person.  We want to make the password easy-to-type, and yet not so short that any desktop PC has the CPU capacity to crack it in a few minutes.

If a password does not use any dictionary words but is simply a four-character random ASCII alphanumeric string, like `DT4K` (alphas all uppercase, not mixed), how long would it take a typical desktop business or home computer with no specialized hardware to crack the encryption? Does going to 5 characters significantly increase the cracking time?

Comment: Likely a pretty trivial amount of time, depends on the key-derivation technique that Acrobat uses. Based on your password requirements, each additional character will multiply the space by about 36 (36^length combinations)

Comment: Assuming just hashing without iteration of the password essentially no time at all. 36^4 = 1,679,616. Further, a common document format will provide a "crib" so correct decryption can be easily confirmed. If you are looking for good secrecy, that is a level of secrecy your clients expect, you really need to hire a security domain expert.

Comment: We don't need "secrecy".  We need a reasonable deterrent to invasions of privacy.

Comment: @zaph: What's the typical time for the "does this password work" test?  200ms?

Comment: There are two parts, deriving a key from the password, and decryption a small potion, just enough to reach common text such as in a salutation. If the key derivation is just a hash, say SHA-256 then that takes under 1us. I suspect the decryption and crib testing would be under 100us, I will test. What should be done is to use an iterated hash function such as PBKDF2, password_hash, bcrypt or similar functions with a count designed to take substantial computation time.

Comment: Update: An AES-128 decrypt of 68 bytes takes under 1us. Thus a hash + decrypt + compare would take under 2us so about 500K passwords could be attempted per second. (My tests were done on a laptop, damn computers are fast these days, )

Comment: WRT a 256-bit key, attackers do not attack the key, that is just not possible, they attack the password the key was derived from.

Comment: I really don't understand the close-votes and downvotes. It's like you have to come to this site already knowing the answer.  What ever happened to being ignorant about something and asking a question about it?? This is not my area at all.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: no, and no.

Longer answer: alphanumeric means A-Za-z0-9, right? That's 62 possible characters, or 5.95 bits of [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)). Since entropy is additive, 4 characters are roughly 24 bits, and 5 are about 30. To put that into comparison, 10 bits mean the attacker has to try about a thousand possible keys, 20 bits are a million, 30 bits about a billion. That's almost nothing these days. 56 bit DES was [cracked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) using brute force in 1998, today people worry that 128 bit AES might not be safe enough.

If i were you, I'd try to use something like [diceware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diceware). That's a list of 7776 easily pronounced words. You can use a random number generator to pick a passphrase from these words, and each word will have about 12.9 bits of entropy. So 5 words are about 65 bits, which for the kind of data you have might be an acceptable level of security, while being easily remembered or communicated via phone.

Why 7776 words? Well, 7776 is 6*6*6*6*6, so you can roll a die five times and get a number, and just look up the corresponding word on the list.

Comment: Have you even read my answer? "So 5 words are about 65 bits" I never suggested using one word.

Comment: @zaph He's suggesting he uses 5 words from that list, so 7776^5 attempts

Comment: Correct, I did not correctly understand the answer WRT the permutation of the words. That is a lot of typing, consider use on a phone keyboard but none-the-less is does seem secure. Still FUD: "today people worry that 128 bit AES might not be safe enough", what people, the man in the street or cryptologists.

Answer (score -2):

My bank sends statements encrypted and uses a combination of my name and birth date. I'm not a huge fan of that idea, but provided you use information that's unlikely to be known to an attacker you'll get a greater level of security than from four or five character alphanumeric passwords.

Comment: Change your bank. That information is easily known and every user of the bank knows the scheme.

Answer (score -2):

This would take less than an 25 seconds even with the most rudimentary tools. There are precomplied rainbow tables for passwords this short that can run in seconds on decent PC's. Password length, NOT complexity, are what make a password difficult to crack. I would highly recomend giving them a longer password, but make it something eaisly recalled. Maybe you entire business name salted with your street address number at the end. Please take at least some precautions. Having a four character password is barely better than not having one at all.

[How Strong is your Password?](https://www.msecure.com/blog/how-strong-is-your-password/)

Comment: To be secure make sure your password is not on any of the common [password lists](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/tree/master/Passwords).